# php refresh current page?

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have a page which,

If a variable is set(in a session)
it will do an action,
then it unsets the session.

Now it has to refresh itself.

This is where i am stuck.

Is there a way to get the exact url to the current page?

or is there a function to do this?

so `header('location: ???');`

Comment: I came here because I was interested in the POST/Redirect/GET" (PRG) pattern, which attempts to eliminate the warning message that browsers give for POST only used for keeping arguments intact or secret. But that pattern fails when you try to share forms in one file, since the main program must be requested by a GET.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is a server generated variable. Only GET,POST,a and COOKIES are susceptible to user interference. (with the possible exception of headers like "Referrer")

Comment: Those server generated variables can be modified, so you should still consider sanitizing them.

Comment: Those who argue it should be sanitized don't really understand what they are talking about. REQUEST_URI holds the URL where you currently are, so if there's any security issue with going to this URL, the harm is already done. Redirecting to where you already are has no security implication.

Comment: So there's no chance an infected server could have this modified... sounds like an M$ support tech :P

Comment: @RobertM. nope, it is redirecting you to the current url. As already said, the damage would already be done.

Comment: put a die() after reload header to prevent code execution below this row.

Answer (score 24):

PHP refresh current page

With PHP code:

```
<?php
$secondsWait = 1;
header("Refresh:$secondsWait");
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Note: Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

if you send any output, you can use javascript:

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.reload(true);</script>';
?>
```

When this method receives a true value as argument, it will cause the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.

Or you can explicitly use "meta refresh" (with pure html):

```
<?php
$secondsWait = 1;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'.$secondsWait.'">';
?>
```

Greetings and good code,

Answer (score 6):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` should work.

Answer (score 3):

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

will also work

Comment: This will only work if you display the filename in the URL. So, URL rewrite definitely won't work.

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple:

```php
header("refresh: 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant one is

```
header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
exit;
```