# How to refresh the current page

Tags: php, drupal

I'm customizing a module in Drupal and in that module I'd like to refresh the current page right after an if statement, how can I refresh the current page in PHP

Comment: This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8131377/1292092). Ensure that you protect yourself against an infinite redirect loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't in PHP if you've already outputted something (since all `headers` must be sent before output begins).

If you haven't outputted:

```
header('Location:: current_page_url');
or
header("Refresh:0");
```

Better way is to do it through Javascript with the `window` object

```
$window.location.reload();
```

Comment: How can I add that js in my php code? should I make a js file and add my js to it?

Comment: You would need to it via `<script src="">`, by creating a .js file. It's not exactly something that can be easily explainde in a comment if one doesn't know JS. I'd recommend using the PHP now after revisiting your question and if you don't have any output (since JS loads after PHP execution is typically finished).

Answer (score 3):

Php offers the following function to invoke a page refresh

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

If you require a page redirect you can use the following.

```
header("Refresh:0; url=redirect_page.php");
```

Comment: Refresh is not a valid HTTP header even though it is implemented in most browsers. There is a standard way also which should be used, which is the Location header.

Answer (score 2):

just 
     header("Refresh:0");

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned the "Drupal Way":

```php
drupal_goto(current_path());
```

This exact scenario is tested in `modules/simpletest/tests/common_test.module` function `common_test_init()`:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function common_test_init() {
  if (variable_get('common_test_redirect_current_path', FALSE)) {
    drupal_goto(current_path());
  }
  if (variable_get('common_test_link_to_current_path', FALSE)) {
    drupal_set_message(l('link which should point to the current path', current_path()));
  }
}
```

Comment: this would fail with query parameters. `example.com/q?a=b` will redirect to `example.com/q`