# how to redirect to the same page after editing data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

sensei. can you help me with my code? i wan to redirect page to the same page after edit it.

here is my controller

```
function edit_book(){
$editBook = array(
    'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
    'book_title' => $this->input->post('book_title'),
    'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
    'author' => $this->input->post('author')
    ):
    $this->m_profile->edit_book($data1, $data, 'book_data');
    redirect('app/book')
}
```

suppose im editing the data from page number 3. how can i redirect to page 3 (app/book/3) again after submit the edited data?

i have try to solve it by get URI value(suppose the page is app/book/3)<-- i need this '3'to put in redirect code. so i implement this code from many stackeroverflow answer, hope to get some array i can use

```
$url =  "//{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
$escaped_url = htmlspecialchars( $url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
$query_str = parse_url($escaped_url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query_str, $query_params);
print_r($query_params);
```

but it results array()or null. anyone can help me. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to the same page in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130990/how-to-redirect-to-the-same-page-in-php)

Comment: have you tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` ?

Comment: You can get `3` using `$config[‘uri_segment’]` in CI

Comment: yeah, it shows my uri. i need the value of my last uri segment (the 3) where do i get it? @Cashbee

Comment: Where r u redirect your page edit_book or book please explain me

Comment: thats edit_book is action to update data, after that it redirect to app/book that shows the edit result @LomeshKelwadkar

Comment: redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Answer (score -1):

In the controller need to pass the last value like "3" as argument so that any edited value can be pass to the controller. And then after editing the code you can redirect by the php header function with the passed value as argument to redirect on the same page like this example:

```
<?php     
function edit_book($id){

Your all edited codes here.

// To redirect to the same page with avalue
redirect('same_controller/method/'.$id, 'refresh');
}
?>
```

Comment: It is not really specified in the post itself, but the tags says codeigniter and the syntax looks like it is using functions of codeigniter. It also has a `redirect()` function. Why use `header()` instead? Also the full hardcoded URL is not needed. And why the `die()` there?

Comment: Ok for the codigniter, need to use redirect function where need to pass id on the routing of the URL.

Answer (score -1):

```
function edit_book(){
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $editBook = array(
        'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
        'book_title' => $this->input->post('book_title'),
        'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
        'author' => $this->input->post('author')
        ):
        $this->m_profile->edit_book($data1, $data, 'book_data');
        $url = base_url('app/book/'.$id);
        redirect( $url)
    }

    function book($id = NULL)
    {
        //get record using $id;

    }
```

try below code me be solve u r issue. i have pass id in url.

Comment: `$id` is not pagination id. Read question again. First understand it then give answer. Don't  just dump answer without any effort.